# Copy files with auto rename

Tags: vba, excel

I have two files with static names and I want use VBA (Excel) to copy these files to another place, but original names are used, so Windows 7 shows these options:
`Copy and overwrite`, `don´t copy` and `copy with rename original file`.

I have something like this:

```
Sub CopyFiles() Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileExt As String
FromPath = "D:\"
ToPath = "D:\Mobil\"
FileExt = "*.txt*"
If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
  FromPath = FromPath & "\"
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")      
FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath     
MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Is somehow possible use third option with VBA?

Comment: Are you using vba in Excel? If so did you write vba code and what does your code look like?

Comment: I try something like that:

`Sub CopyFiles()
Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    FromPath = "D:\"
    ToPath = "D:\Mobil\"

    FileExt = "*.txt*"

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub`
My code just only copy file and only if destiny path doesn´t contain source file(s).

Comment: you could use xcopy on the command line type xcopy /? in a command window to see help.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx

Comment: I try `echo f | xcopy /f /y D:\S136.txt D:\Mobil\ ` but this not help me with renaming original file.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help:

```
Sub copyAndRenameIfExistsElseCopy()

Dim fname As String, dname As String
fname = "C:\temp\folder1\one.txt"
dname = "C:\temp\folder2\one.txt"
rname = "C:\temp\folder2\one_renamed.txt"
If Dir(dname) <> "" Then
    FileCopy fname, rname
Else
    FileCopy fname, dname
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @Roland, but Your code help me only once. Next day, when I wanna copy changed source file via VBA I need another name.